# How to use specific host ip address on kvm?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virsh, ubuntu-22.04

Have a dedicated Ubuntu Server host with a single network interface but with two ip address:

```bash
root@server:~# cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml 
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eno3:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: 00:00:00:00:00:00
            set-name: eno3
            addresses: [IP-A/24, IP-B/32]
```

When `IP-A` is the native ip address assigned to the server and `IP-B` is an additional ip address that I have contracted. When configuring using `netplan apply` everything works very well, the WEB server exits through the IP address `IP-A` and from curl I can see how it is possible to access the internet from `IP-B`:

```bash
wget -qO- http://checkip.dyndns.com/ --bind-address IP-A
... Current IP Address: IP-A
wget -qO- http://checkip.dyndns.com/ --bind-address IP-B
... Current IP Address: IP-B
```

The problem is that I also have a virtual machine with `kvm` (`virsh`), how can I make the virtual machine go out to the internet using `IP-B` and not `IP-A` as it does by default?

My network interfaces:

```bash
root@yhojann:~# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 11:11:11:11:11:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet IP-A/24 brd x.x.x.255 scope global dynamic eno3
       valid_lft 63801sec preferred_lft 63801sec
    inet IP-B/32 scope global eno3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ffff::fff:ffff:ffff:ffff/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 22:22:22:22:22:22 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
17: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 33:33:33:33:33:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
18: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:44:44:44:44:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
20: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:44:44:44:44:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I have tried to find out if it is possible to configure the kvm network using `virsh net-edit default`

but I have not found any reference that allows to make use of a specific egress ip address of the main host without having to use a new virtual interface and redirect packets with iptables, since this causes a great latency in the connectivity.

Is there a more "native" way to tell kvm to use the specific IP?

The ip addresses and mac addresses shown are for reference only. I make use of ufw to manage the connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign IP-B to the virtual machine:

- Create a bridge interface.
- Move `eno3` to the bridge.

  Note that this will probably result in loss of network connectivity, so you'll want to make sure you are performing these changes over some sort of out-of-band connection (like a serial console or graphic console).

  Exactly how to perform these steps in a persistent fashion varies from distribution to distribution; whatever you're using I'm sure you can find appropriate documentation.
- Assign IP-A to the bridge device.
- Attach your virtual machine to the bridge.

  If you're creating your vm using `virt-install`, that might look like:

  ```
  virt-install --network bridge=br0 ...
  ```

  If you're creating the domain XML manually, that means an `<interface>` stanza like this:

  ```
  <interface type="bridge">
    <source bridge="br0"/>
    <model type="virtio"/>
  </interface>
  ```
- Assign `eth0` (or whatever the interface is called) **inside** the virtual machine IP-B

This gives you:

[image]

Both your host and your virtual machine are connected to the same network.